# Element that is below appears as if it is above other elements

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

I am following a tutorial set out by one of my tutors for a design course and as he is modeling the hair of his 3D model, the hair seems to go under, as it should be expected to. Mine turns out like this:
[image: Hair is seen overlapping the top part of the hair.]
[image: Hair is actually below]

So I don't know the best way to explain it but basically a element is shown as being on top when it actually is below the other elements. It renders fine, but when modeling normally, it is hard to arrange the hair properly as it looks off putting to me.

Can anyone help me with this situation? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does it happen always with this element or only when selected?

Comment: This happens all the time. It is fine when rendering though